# How to operate on a multi-index object in pyomo accessing only one of its indexes?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, gurobi

I would like to know how to operate over pyomo multiple index objects just by employing one of the index.

This question may be a bit stupid, but I have not found a possible solution. In my model, the decision variable (x) is the surface of each crop (j) in each year (t). Therefore, x is a multi-index variable:

```py
model.x = pyomo.Var(model.crop, model.t, domain = pyomo.NonNegativeIntegers)
```

Eg, model.x should be indexed like model.x[crop, year]

I want to create two resources constraints that limit the cropping area and the water consumption (which has only the j index) to the established maximum per year. Something like the following code:

```
def area_constr(model, year):
    return sum(model.x[crop, year] for crop in model.crop for year in model.t) <=\
          model.total_cropping_area_n[year] 
model.area_constr = pyomo.Constraint(model.a, model.n, rule = area_constr, 
doc = 'Restricción de superficie disponible')
```

```
def water_constr(model, crop, year):
return sum(model.x\[crop, year\] \* model.crop_water_demand\[crop\]
for crop in model.a for year in model.n) \<= total_water_endowment\[year\]
model.water_constr = pyomo.Constraint(model.a, model.n, rule = water_constr)
```

I'm not able to make it work since I obtained the following message:

`KeyError: "Index '0' is not valid for indexed component 'x'"`

for the area constraint and f and for the water constraint add up the water consumption of all crops in all years, not year by year.

How can I operate using just one index? or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `area_constr` is that while you are correctly passing in the year value to the rule because you want to make an area constraint *for each year* you are overriding that by supplying the variable `year` again inside of the summation.

Here is an example that shows what I think you intend.  Realize that in each of the 2 constraints, you should be using the values that are passed in as function parameters as shown.

If your area limits *change by year* then you could (and should) index that data with `(crop, year)` tuples in the dictionary and index the corresponding parameter the same way.

#### Code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

### DATA

years = [2023, 2024, 2025]

water_demand = {    'corn': 1.5,
                    'rice': 2.3,
                    'wheat': 1.1}

water_limit = {     2023: 10.1,
                    2024: 12.3,
                    2025: 9.8}

area_limit = {      'corn': 10_000,
                    'rice': 12_500,
                    'wheat': 8_800}

### MODEL

m = pyo.ConcreteModel('crops')

# SETS
m.Y = pyo.Set(initialize=years, doc='year')
m.C = pyo.Set(initialize=water_demand.keys(), doc='crop')

# PARAMS
m.demand     = pyo.Param(m.C, initialize=water_demand)
m.limit      = pyo.Param(m.Y, initialize=water_limit)
m.area_limit = pyo.Param(m.C, initialize=area_limit)

# VARS
m.plant = pyo.Var(m.C, m.Y, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, doc='amount to plant of crop c in year y')

# CONSTRAINTS

# 1.  Don't bust the water limit FOR EVERY YEAR
def water_lim_constraint(m, y):
    # the "y" in this comes from the function params, we just need to supply "c" internally
    return sum(m.plant[c, y]*water_demand[c] for c in m.C) <= m.limit[y]
m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(m.Y, rule=water_lim_constraint, doc='total water limit by year')

# 2.  Don't overplant FOR EVERY CROP, FOR EVERY YEAR
def plant_limit(m, c, y):
    # in this constraint, the limit is applied for every year and crop, which
    # are supplied as function arguments
    return m.plant[c, y] <= m.area_limit[c]
m.C2 = pyo.Constraint(m.C, m.Y, rule=plant_limit, doc='area planting limit by crop and year')

m.pprint()
```

#### Output:

```
4 Set Declarations
    C : crop
        Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'corn', 'rice', 'wheat'}
    C2_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    C*Y :    9 : {('corn', 2023), ('corn', 2024), ('corn', 2025), ('rice', 2023), ('rice', 2024), ('rice', 2025), ('wheat', 2023), ('wheat', 2024), ('wheat', 2025)}
    Y : year
        Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {2023, 2024, 2025}
    plant_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    C*Y :    9 : {('corn', 2023), ('corn', 2024), ('corn', 2025), ('rice', 2023), ('rice', 2024), ('rice', 2025), ('wheat', 2023), ('wheat', 2024), ('wheat', 2025)}

3 Param Declarations
    area_limit : Size=3, Index=C, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key   : Value
         corn : 10000
         rice : 12500
        wheat :  8800
    demand : Size=3, Index=C, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key   : Value
         corn :   1.5
         rice :   2.3
        wheat :   1.1
    limit : Size=3, Index=Y, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key  : Value
        2023 :  10.1
        2024 :  12.3
        2025 :   9.8

1 Var Declarations
    plant : amount to plant of crop c in year y
        Size=9, Index=plant_index
        Key             : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
         ('corn', 2023) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
         ('corn', 2024) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
         ('corn', 2025) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
         ('rice', 2023) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
         ('rice', 2024) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
         ('rice', 2025) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('wheat', 2023) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('wheat', 2024) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('wheat', 2025) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

2 Constraint Declarations
    C1 : total water limit by year
        Size=3, Index=Y, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                                                                : Upper : Active
        2023 :  -Inf : 1.5*plant[corn,2023] + 2.3*plant[rice,2023] + 1.1*plant[wheat,2023] :  10.1 :   True
        2024 :  -Inf : 1.5*plant[corn,2024] + 2.3*plant[rice,2024] + 1.1*plant[wheat,2024] :  12.3 :   True
        2025 :  -Inf : 1.5*plant[corn,2025] + 2.3*plant[rice,2025] + 1.1*plant[wheat,2025] :   9.8 :   True
    C2 : area planting limit by crop and year
        Size=9, Index=C2_index, Active=True
        Key             : Lower : Body              : Upper   : Active
         ('corn', 2023) :  -Inf :  plant[corn,2023] : 10000.0 :   True
         ('corn', 2024) :  -Inf :  plant[corn,2024] : 10000.0 :   True
         ('corn', 2025) :  -Inf :  plant[corn,2025] : 10000.0 :   True
         ('rice', 2023) :  -Inf :  plant[rice,2023] : 12500.0 :   True
         ('rice', 2024) :  -Inf :  plant[rice,2024] : 12500.0 :   True
         ('rice', 2025) :  -Inf :  plant[rice,2025] : 12500.0 :   True
        ('wheat', 2023) :  -Inf : plant[wheat,2023] :  8800.0 :   True
        ('wheat', 2024) :  -Inf : plant[wheat,2024] :  8800.0 :   True
        ('wheat', 2025) :  -Inf : plant[wheat,2025] :  8800.0 :   True

10 Declarations: Y C demand limit area_limit plant_index plant C1 C2_index C2
[Finished in 267ms]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, awesome example! Now I really understand how Pyomo contraints need to be made :)